# BizTalk Server to consume SOAP web methods without orchestrations

Tags: soap, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-orchestrations

Using BizTalk Server 2013, I want to read (pull) data from a web service and push it onto a SharePoint back-end system. The web service exposes web methods in SOAP. BizTalk has a default SOAP adapter. However, it seems that to read SOAP messages, BizTalk needs to know what XML schema to expect. Hence an orchestration in BizTalk is required to map inbound XML schemas from the web service methods to the expected outcome.

Orchestrations seem to be an overkill for this scenario. Is there a way to pull from SOAP web services using message based routing (i.e. from the BizTalk Admin Console) only?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.  What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf How? Can this be done without developing a BizTalk project in Visual Studio?

Comment: That's not what you asked, you asked if it can be done without an Orchestration, which can be done.  You still need to have the schemas etc. in a project.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Basic Http Adapter can do in your case.
Even though SOAP Adapter is available, Microsoft too recommends using WCF BasicHttpAdapter instead.
[Refer here: Microsoft Blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0fe5c387-1730-4b3c-ad06-e03e0c24db33/biztalk-server-upgrade-project-soap-adapter-deprecated-but-is-it-still-supported?forum=biztalkgeneral)

Comment: You mean using the WCF BasicHttpAdapter from the BizTalk Administration Console to create message routing (i.e. receive locations, receive adapters, send locations, etc.), WITHOUT having to develop orchestrations in Visual Studio?

Comment: Also please note that the web services are not in WFC and are beyond my control.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible.

Make sure to add generated schemas for this soap endpoint. Map the request schema to  your sharepoint document.

Then deploy your schemas and maps.

Set the map to your `Receive Port Properties -> Inbound Maps`

Comment: In Visual Studio, I managed to load the schemas from the WSDL file using the "Add Generated Items..." option. Now, do I have to create a separate schema for the "sharepoint document"? And how is the mapping done? @ed bangga

Comment: You only need a map to your target (sharepoint document) if it is in xml. But if you don't need a mapping, you can load the request xml (from soap) directly to sharepoint using BizTalk SharePoint adapter.

Comment: I have created a new BizTalk project in VS, imported the schemas by using the "Add Generated Items..." option, rebuild and deployed the project. Now in BizTalk Server Administration Console, I can see the project (which has the schemas). Now what Receive port adapter shall I use? Note that the web services are not WCF.

Comment: Create send port then use Wcf-custom, basichttpbinding. Add filter BTS.ReceivePortName=YourReceivePort. Then create another SendPort(SharePoint Adapter) with Filter BTS.SPName=YourWCFCustomSendPortName.

Comment: So now I have 2 send ports ("CustomSend" and "SharePoint") and 1 receive port ("CustomReceive"):
  "CustomSend" sends a request to the SOAP URL.
  "CustomReceive" reads the response from the SOAP URL.
  "SharePoint" sends the response to the SharePoint list.

I am not sure of: 
  1. "CustomReceive" - will this wait for responses from the SOAP web service?
  2. The order of execution of the ports.

Comment: @Usering If you are getting a Syncronous response you shouldn't have a separate Receive Location/Port for the response. What you do need is your second send port have the filter as per ed bangga's comment. If you are getting an Asynchronous response rather than a Synchronous response, then you probably will need an Orchestration

Answer (score 0):

It is possible
Just don't forget to add the soap operation in the send port. But you can call only one method per send port